# Wifi drop warning

Tags: connection-issues, mobile-data, automation, samsung-galaxy-note

I live in a house where the router seems to just turn off every now and then. It's not really a problem as long as I'm aware when my phone switches to data, but sometimes I'll have watched multiple videos before I notice the lack of a wifi symbol. This is definitely a problem because I have a limited data plan.

I have a Galaxy Note 5. Does anyone know of a simple way for the phone to warn me when I drop off wifi?

Comment: Honestly I'd just keep data off unless I need to use it, that way you surely get notified (no internet access at all) when WiFi somehow drops.

Comment: Just keep the data off, and your phone will warn you when it happen:)

Comment: Good idea, but for personal reasons I need the data on whenever I don't have wifi, especially when I'm out of the house. I'm just looking for something more convienient

Comment: The problem is that the functionality to locate the phone if it gets lost relies on an internet connection.  But it's high time Google implemented using mobile data only for this when it is otherwise switched off.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think Android devices have a built-in alert or notification to cater for this

You can achieve this by automation. I prefer [MacroDroid](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.arlosoft.macrodroid) being easy to learn and free ( upto 5 macros )

**Trigger:** WiFi state change → Disconnect from network → choose network or any

**Actions:**

1. Play sound → Choose a sound from drop down list.
2. Popup message → Type whatever you want to be displayed when Wi-Fi is disconnected.

This will give you an *audio alert* + a *pop-up message* on your screen.

Comment: This app is fantastic, and exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks. Sure it is a great app and I often suggest that. See [some solutions](http://android.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A131553+macrodroid)  offered - it is a very versatile app . Happy automation :)

Comment: Does "disconnect from network" trigger regardless of whether the loss of connection has happened at the router end or the phone end?  My phone every now and again mysteriously loses sight of my home wifi connection although the router is still alive and connected.  I would like to be warned when this happens.

Comment: @Stewart yes, it does-what matters is that connection is lost, not *why*//I don't have this macro running but you can test it out

Comment: A few other options that would be most useful for the purpose: (a) being able to override silent/do not disturb status (b) triggering only when I'm actually at home, as determined by GPS.  I don't suppose MacroDroid provides these?

Comment: Yes to both... That's the fun of automation. You can try out the actions mentioned. The app has templates uploaded by users that would help you