# Why does my phone report "network unavailable" every time I return home?

Tags: wi-fi, networking

At home I have a router with several devices wired and over wifi. Everything works fine, including my Android LG cellphone, which connects to cell over wifi.  I'm in a rural area with no direct cell service, so it's wifi only for internet and calls.

When I go somewhere and come back, I can't receive phone calls or texts.  The web browser still works. The wifi settings shows the router, and puts on appearances of being okay.  But attempts to call out fail with "network unavailable".  By powering off and rebooting, everything goes back to normal.

If it's relevant: when I go out, it's mostly through areas with no service of any kind at all. (AM broadcast radio, barely.)  In town, I have regular cell and everything's fine.

My main question is: why?  What is a permanent fix?

Being absent-minded, I often forget to do the power cycle every time I return home. So a secondary question, if the first can't be answered, is if there's a way to automate the power cycle every time I'm out of range and return to within range of my home router? Or at least have a beep, popup or something to remind me?

Comment: Power cycling is the same as putting the device on aeroplane mode for a few seconds and disabling it. Both reset the network connections// You can use [MacroDroid](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.arlosoft.macrodroid) to automate either (power or aeroplane mode cycling but the latter requires root) // [You can try this for reboot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ciEOM.png)

Comment: For a warning see [this](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/171259/131553) which can be adjusted for your needs